# Multiple Self-referencing relationships

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have an Abstract Class which all DomainClasses are extending.
This Abstracte Class looks like this:

```
abstract class DomainBase { 
    Date created = new Date(), modified = new Date()
    User createdBy, modifiedBy
    int dataStatus = 30 
}
```

My DomainClass `User` also extends the abstract Class and has multiple self-referencing relationship:

```
User principal

static hasMany = [employees: User, skills: UserSkill,...]
static mappedBy = [employees: 'none' ]
```

UserSkill:

```
class UserSkill extends DomainBase {

    String category
    String name 
    static belongsTo = [User]
    static hasMany = [users: User]
    static mappedBy = [users: 'skills']

    static mapping = {
        table 'skill'
        users column: 'skill_id', joinTable: 'user_skills' 
      }
}
```

With that i'm getting an MappingException:

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: broken column mapping for: 
createdBy.skills of: de.streit.user.UserSkill
```

How do I mapp the classes correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Stepping away from Grails for a moment... you've got an object-oriented design problem. According to your design, *DomainBase* sits at the top of your hierarchy. Because of this *DomainBase* should not depend on its subclasses. Here's why:

According to the [Liskov substitution principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle), if class B extends from class A, then an instance of class B should be usable wherever an instance of class A is expected.

For example, if class *Duck* extends class *Bird*, I can honestly say *a Duck* **is a** *Bird*. My nose would not get any longer. If a method expects a *Bird* and I give it a *Duck* the method won't know the difference.

In your case, a *User* cannot be a *DomainClass* because a *DomainClass* **has a** user. Can a *Bird* have a *Duck*? Nope. A *Bird* should not know anything about *Duck*s. Animals aside, your class hierarchy violates this principle. But this can be fixed :)

## Solution

As long as you're using Groovy 2.3 or grater, a [Groovy trait](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-traits.html) can address your issue.

First, create a trait  somewhere in grails-app/src/main/groovy/. It's best if you place it in the same Groovy (Java) package as your domain classes.

```
package xzy

trait Auditable { 
    Date created = new Date(), modified = new Date()
    User createdBy, modifiedBy
    int dataStatus = 30 
}
```

Then, have your domain classes implement the trait.

```
package xyz

class User implements Auditable {
     User principal

     static hasMany = [employees: User, skills: UserSkill,...]
     static mappedBy = [employees: 'none' ]
}

class UserSkill implements Auditable {

    String category
    String name 
    static belongsTo = [User]
    static hasMany = [users: User]
    static mappedBy = [users: 'skills']

    static mapping = {
        table 'skill'
        users column: 'skill_id', joinTable: 'user_skills' 
      }
}
```

This works because your domain classes will magically get the properties defined in the trait (created, createBy, and dataStatus) without baggage of inheritance. Plus, if a method expects an *Audiable*, you can pass it a *User* or *UserSkill* and the method wouldn't know the difference.

Watch this: **Users** *and* **UserSkills** *are* **Auditable**. Makes sense huh?